# Get Android source code from External Resource

Tags: java, android

We would like to integrate hundred plus small/mid-level games into our android application.
We don't want to compile all the games source codes within the android application.
**To minimize app size we would like to receive game source code (java, XML, resource, etc. )from the server on the fly.**

The external resources like icons and images can be implemented easily. But we are stuck to run Java and XML code on the fly. Is this possible somehow?

Seeking expert advice.

Comment: Not an Android expert so I may have missed something, but if that was possible on an unrooted device you could run any unverified code no matter the security settings and circumvent any app store security since it won't see the real code running. I'd look at dynamically installing precompiled APKs as in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/InstallApkSessionApi.java instead, that seems to be a supported way.

Comment: (or run it inside some sort of emulator or web window)

Comment: perhaps https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery